# tooltip for zoomed image map in IE9

Tags: html, css, zooming

Why in IE9, `alt` doesn't appear on defined area of image-map, when I use zoom:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #wrap {zoom:50%; -moz-transform:scale(50%); -webkit-transform:scale(50%) }
</style>

<div id="wrap">
  <img src="http://www.content.onemexico.net/rosa.jpg" width="640" height="640" usemap="#theMap">
  <map name="theMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="240,240,400,400" href="#" alt="RosesByAlt" title="RosesByTitle">
  </map>
</div>
```

Is there any solution for IE9, to show text (`alt` or `title`) on the defined clickable area of zoomed image?